# C# excel, find the color of the cell from template

Tags: c#, excel, colors, excel-2010

I need to programmatically find the color cells in Excel. if I change the color manually everything is fine(use interior.color). In case you turn it over template create problem.

x.interior.color returns white for any color.

Ok I nead use some template Excel -> Desing:
Then I nead after change read the color of cell

Color is orange but :

Excel.Range oPivotTableCell.Interior.Color = 16777215.0    (this is white)

where find real color or template color for specific cell?

Comment: You sure your getting the right cell? Try simplifying it and making absolutely sure you are selecting the cell you want to get

Comment: Check `Style.Interior.Color`. `Range.Interior` returns the values explicitly set for a range, not those set by a `Style`. A PivotTable's colors are typically set by a style.

Comment: to : pseudonym : yes, I´m absolutly sure. Because when I change the color manually ( HOME - fill color) everything works.

Comment: To Panagiotis Kanavos, Thank you for the reply but the cell still can not find the right color , we still only white. I'm looking for it right? `foreach (Excel.Range oPivotTableCell in TargetRange.Cells)`
        `{`
            `var p12 = oPivotTableCell.Style.Interior.Color;`
            `var p13 = oPivotTableCell.Interior.Color;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is :

excel.Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

good way to take excel.range is select cells and get range

excel.Range test = (excel.Range)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
test.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color